# Facebook Events Creation Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm trying to create Facebook event page using Graph API but as per there documentation and error "events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher" seems, its no more available, so anybody can help me out on this?

Answer (score 3):

As you found out already, it is not possible anymore. There is no workaround. If someone else is able to do it, they must have a special agreement with Facebook. One you will most likely not get.